# How would I populate a list with another function in python?

Tags: python, arrays, json

How would I populate certain strings in the `currentRow` from another function? For example, I need to make the value of `dividendsandgrowth` equal to `.02*"beginningBalance"`. I was thinking of doing this in another function below the `getResults()` and then feed it to `getResults` and print it out through if `__name__ == "__main__"`. I'm new to python, and any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
import pprint


def getResults():
    mylist = []
    for n in range(1, 37+1):
        currentRow = {"age": 23 + n, "numOfYears": n,
                      "beginningBalance": n, "currentSalary": 72_000.00,
                      "dividendsAndGrowth": n , "yearlyDeposit": 8_640.00,
                      "yearlyTotal": n}
        mylist.append(currentRow)


    return mylist

def dividendsAndGrowth():

return value


if __name__ == "__main__":
    z = getResults()
    pprint.pprint(z)
```

Comment: Take the results from ```getResults()``` and use that as a parameter to the ```dividendsAndGrowth()``` function and then inside this ```dividendsAndGrowth()```, you iterate through the list and change the values and then return the results

Comment: could you show me an example of what you mean, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following; though I suspect someone'll have a more
succinct way of doing this.

```
import pprint


def getResults():
    mylist = []
    for n in range(1, 37+1):
        currentRow = {"age": 23 + n, "numOfYears": n,
                      "beginningBalance": n, "currentSalary": 72_000.00,
                      "dividendsAndGrowth": n , "yearlyDeposit": 8_640.00,
                      "yearlyTotal": n}
        mylist.append(currentRow)


    return mylist


def dividendsAndGrowth(in_list):
    retval = []
    for x in in_list:
        x["dividendsAndGrowth"] = x["beginningBalance"] * 0.02
        retval.append(x)
    return retval


if __name__ == "__main__":
    z = getResults()
    newz = dividendsAndGrowth(z)
    pprint.pprint(z)
```

Comment: thanks this helped. I ended up putting the for loop inside the get results function to be able to manipulate the database I'm dealing with. I'm still working out the kinks. Need the beginningBalance to get replaced with the new yearlyTotal every line and the yearlyTotal is the sum of the beginningbalance + dividendandgrowth + yearlydeposit